# since without perfect tense in the main clause

Tags: grammar, tense

According to Michael Swan's Practical English Usage, it is possible to use since without perfect tenses in the main clause, especially in sentences about change. The examples given are:

> 1. You're looking much better since your operation.

> 2. She doesn't come round to see us so much since her marriage.

> 3. Since last Sunday I can't stop thinking about you.

> 4. Things weren't going so well since Father's illness.

I'm unable to understand this rule well enough. What about these sentences:

> - I'm living at my friend's house since last Sunday. (= I lived somewhere else before Sunday but now I live with my friend, which is a change).

> - Since coming to London, I play a lot of Cricket (I didn't play much Cricket before coming to London but now I play a lot).

> - I know her since last year (I didn't know her before last year but now I do).*

Are these sentences also correct?

Answer (score 0):

Of your suggestions, I think only the second is both grammatically valid and natural.

"*I'm living*" is the present tense, but that doesn't work well with "since". I think this should be:

> I have been living at my friend's house since last Sunday.

"*I know her*" similarly does not work with since. I think this should be:

> I have known her since last year.

I find it hard to formulate a general rule that covers all these examples.